# Block Floating Point versus Regular Floating Point Arithmetic

Tags: math, architecture, floating-point, fpga

I am wondering when one would use block floating point instead of regular floating point?  At what point is block floating point not good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'd only use block FP when fixed-point doesn't give you the dynamic range needed, and you can't afford the gates or power to go to full FP. It might be appropriate for an FFT, for example (which needs lots of dynamic range), where you need cheap hardware. Block FP will also give you higher precision than full FP for the same word width, assuming that you can live with the dynamic range problem. Lots of stuff on Google. Having said that, I haven't seen a commercial block FP implementation for over 10 years, though I haven't been looking.